# anyone know why this doesn't work? --> [cp_props[x]][1]

Tags: python

this piece of code doesn't work, and i get the "IndexError: list index out of range" error, but not sure why, anyone know why this doesn't work? Thanks.

```
 print([cp_props[x]][1])
```

It should get the name of an item in a list, which is the name of anothert list and then open up the 2nd element in that list???

Okay, so it now works like this:

```
 globals()[cp_props[x]][1]
```

But is there any other more simple way of doing it? Thank you.

Comment: Because arrays start at 0 in every sane language. It makes the math *way* easier.

Comment: `[cp_props[x]]` and `globals()[cp_props[x]]` has two very different meanings. The first creates a list, the second indexes into the globals dictionary.

Comment: oh i see, thanks @JeffMercado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[cp_props[x]]` is a one-element list. Its one and only element is `cp_props[x]`, whatever it is. This is element number 0. There is no element number 1, that's why the selection expression `[1]` fails.

Expression `globals()[cp_props[x]][1]` has a totally different meaning. Reading it from the left to the right:

1. `globals()` is a list of global variables.
2. `globals()[cp_props[x]]` is a selection from that list - that is, some global variable.
3. `globals()[cp_props[x]][1]` is the second element of *that* global variable.

Comment: i would put it in a print function, so,     print([cp_props[x]][1]), it that still a problem? Should i use curved brackets?

Comment: Oh, thank you very much, that explains it, thank you, so that is ok as it is then with globals()?

Comment: You should educate yourself about the use of parentheses in Python.

Comment: yeah i probably should, but i am a beginner and just really like experimenting in python, thanks though @DYZ